# Tax issue with my site

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.2.2, tax

I am having an issue where when I try to select that the tax calculation should be based on "shipping address", The tax is not being shown. If I select "Shipping Origin" the tax shows. I need the tax to be calculated by shipping address. Can anyone help? [image]

Comment: hey can u check what you have saved in this configuration  Stores> Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings.

Comment: Have you used any other extension for TAX?

Comment: As per your screen-shoot i checked you used AVATAX extension,  it might be possible it conflict. Disable this extension and check.